# jQuery PowerTip Trouble W/ Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having a lot of trouble getting PowerTip plugin to work on a new WP site. The site is closed for development, but I'll try to be as specific as possible. Hopefully I missed something simple because this seems like a great plugin.

The script jquery.powertip.js was uploaded to my theme's JS directory.
The css file jquery.powertip.css was uploaded to my theme's css directory.

I call the script in the header directly above:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.powertip.css">
<script src="js/jquery.powertip.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've also tried the direct http link instead or a relative one, but that didn't make a difference. Here's an example of an img snippet I'm testing the plugin on.

```
<img class="productImage" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/cow.png" title="This is a test">
```

I've added the following funtion to my main.js file as follows:

```
$('.productImage').powerTip({
    placement: 'ne' // north-east tooltip position
});
```

I also add this to my main css file as recommended by the plugin documentation:

```
#powerTip {
    position: absolute !important;
    display: none !important;
    z-index:2147483647 !important;
}
```

If anyone could help me out I'd really appreciate it. Here's a link the github plugin: [jQuery PowerTip: GitHub](http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/)

Comment: what is your question? what isnt working? what do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead? are there errors in the console? have you tried running the initialization code in the console? have you verified if the include files have been loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have to correctly enqueue Javascript in WordPress themes in order to load it correctly after the main jQuery library and load it in no conflict mode. See [Function Reference/wp enqueue script « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for details on how to use `wp_enqueue_script`and see examples, i.e. for `jquery.powertip.js`:

```
function theme_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.powertip.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.powertip.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_load_scripts' );
```

*The function goes in functions.php of the theme; the script init $('.productImage').powerTip... goes in header.php*

2) Learn to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what javascript is loading on your site and any errors. The console will show you if you still have javascript errors from loading the tooltip script or other conflicts.

3) CSS can be added to the main stylesheet; or, use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style in the same theory as above to keep your custom CSS in a separate style sheet.

```
 function theme_load_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_load_style' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added this function as you suggested:
`function jquery_powertip() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.powertip', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.powertip.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}

add_action( 'call_descriptions', 'jquery_powertip' );`

I also added this call in my header.php:
`do_action( 'call_descriptions' );`
Developer tools is showing the script being loaded, and I do not see any errors. The image title stops rendering with the script running, so I believe it's working at some capacity.

Comment: wp_enqueue_script goes in your theme functions.php file, not in header.php. See http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/

Comment: The function is in the functions.php, and i placed the do_action in the header.php to call the function. Thanks for taking the time to help me out by the way, it's really appreciated.

Comment: I got it working, just had to tweak the css in addition to adding enqueue scripts. Thanks again.